# Need to skip some data depending on data next to it

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to add data to a google form from google sheet. I actually can do that. But know I want to skip some options, I want to skip the days that are Sundays. I have this table->

[image]

Actually I'm using this code to add the options to the form:

```js
function getDataFromSpreadSheet(){
  var [header, ...data] = timeStore.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var choices = {};
  header.forEach(function(title, index){
    choices[title] = data.map(row => row[index]).filter(e => e !== "");
  });
   Logger.log(choices);
  return choices;
}

function populateTimeOptions(){
  var items = googleForm.getItems();
  var choices = getDataFromSpreadSheet();

  items.forEach(function(item){
    var itemTitle = item.getTitle();
     Logger.log(itemTitle);
    if(itemTitle in choices){
      var itemType = item.getType();
      Logger.log(itemType + " " + itemTitle);
      switch(itemType){
        case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
        item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
        default:
        Logger.log("Ignore question", itemTitle);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I don't know to much of JavaScript but I guess it should be a proper way to add data and add filter options.

I hope some can help me.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your data first to remove dates that fall on Sunday before you map the data.

### Sample Code:

```
function getDataFromSpreadSheet(){
  var [header, ...data] = timeStore.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var choices = {};
  header.forEach(function(title, index){
    choices[title] = data.filter(row => row[1] !== 'Sunday').map(row => row[index]).filter(e => e !== "");
  });
   Logger.log(choices);
  return choices;
}
```

### Modifications done:

- Filter `data` by checking if index 1 value is not `Sunday`. `data.filter(row => row[1] !== 'Sunday')`

### Output:

[image]

**Execution log**

```
2:42:55 AM  Notice  Execution started
2:42:56 AM  Info    {Day=[Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday], Date=[07/01/2021, 07/02/2021, 07/03/2021, 07/05/2021, 07/06/2021, 07/07/2021, 07/08/2021, 07/09/2021, 07/10/2021, 07/12/2021, 07/13/2021, 07/14/2021]}
2:42:58 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues so i could update accordingly

Comment: Thank you!!! I didn't know that we can call a map after other map.

Answer (score 1):

`data.forEach(r => {if(r[1] != 'Sunday'});`

Comment: That's just a suggestion.  It's up to you to implement it.